# Monit Web Service(HTTPD) not available

Tags: chef-infra, monitoring, chef-solo, monit

I'm trying to configure monit on my server using chef solo and the [monit cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/monit). When I visit port 2812 response saying `this webpage is not available`. This only when access remotely via a web browser. I get the expected content when curling locally.

#### monit cookbook

```
include_recipe 'monit'

cookbook_file '/etc/monit/conf.d/puma.conf' do
  source 'monit-puma'
  owner 'deploy'
  group 'deploy'
  mode '0755'
  action :create
end

cookbook_file '/etc/monit/conf.d/nginx.conf' do
  source 'monit-nginx'
  owner 'deploy'
  group 'deploy'
  mode '0755'
  action :create
end

execute 'sudo monit reload'
```

#### /etc/monit/conf.d/compat.conf

```
set httpd port 2812
  use address 127.0.0.1
  allow admin:mybestpassword
```

#### default attributes

```
default['monit']['port'] = '2812'
default['monit']['username'] = 'admin'
default['monit']['password'] = '...'
default['monit']['address'] = '0.0.0.0'
default['monit']['allow'] = ['0.0.0.0']
```

#### poise-monit UPDATE

```
monit 'monit' do
  daemon_interval 30
  event_slots 1000
  httpd_port 2812
  httpd_username 'admin'
  httpd_password 'Password1'
  group 'deploy'
end
```

#### poise-monit recipe

```
monit 'monit' do
  daemon_interval 30
  event_slots 1000
  httpd_port 2812
  httpd_username 'admin'
  httpd_password 'Password1'
  group 'deploy'
end


monit_config 'nginx' do
  source 'monit_nginx.conf.erb'
end


monit_config 'puma' do
  source 'monit-puma.conf.erb'
end
```

#### poise-monit generates /etc/monit/monitrc

```
# Generated by Chef for monit[monit]

SET PIDFILE /var/run/monit_real.pid

SET LOGFILE /var/log/monit.log

SET IDFILE /var/lib/monit/id
SET STATEFILE /var/lib/monit/state
SET EVENTQUEUE BASEDIR /var/lib/monit/events SLOTS 1000

SET HTTPD PORT 2812
  ALLOW admin:Password1

INCLUDE /etc/monit/conf.d/*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the README, you need to either set a password or `allow` settings for the node attributes to be used. Otherwise they are ignored for safety. You can check out the `poise-monit` documentation for more detailed instructions on configuring the web UI.

Comment: You did see that the monit cookbook is deprecated, right? You really shouldn't be trying to use it.

Comment: Yes but the documentation is a lot more understandable than poise-monit

Comment: Which part? I wrote both and they are from the same template :)

Comment: I don't really like the poise_service approach. I want to just be able to install monit and use the services that I place under conf.d/

Comment: I modified the recipe using poise-monit but still not working. I've updated the question above

Comment: That should do it. You can confirm in the generated `monit.conf` but it should include `SET HTTPD PORT 2812 ALLOW admin:password1`. You can use the style you have, just use `monit_config` resources instead of `cookbook_file`. Also this setup is extremely insecure unless you are installing Monit 5.16 (which poise-monit doesn't by default yet, waiting for the builds to roll).

Comment: Its not making any changes

Comment: Did it actually have that literally? Assuming you meant `/0` that still shouldn't be possible, the template is an if/else https://github.com/poise/poise-monit/blob/master/chef/templates/monit.conf.erb#L28-L32

Comment: That was my original file. Using poise-monit no files are changed I will post recipe above.

Comment: Check the chef-client output to make sure the resource is actually running.

Comment: I'm seeing it run in the log. But It does not change any of the files. There not git diff feedback in the log either.

Comment: It finally made a change to `/etc/monit/monitrc`. It set the port and allow with username and password but no response in my browser.

Comment: If you flat-out can't reach the service, check for a firewall or other network-level things. Once the config file is rendered it's a case of "what you see is what you get".

Comment: Oh, another thing to remember, if you switched from one cookbook to another in-place look for `/etc/monit/conf.d/compat.conf` that the `monit` cookbook creates. It would have to be removed when upgrading. I should note that in the docs.

Comment: I does appear to be that the port is closed after checking nmap

Answer (score 1):

```
set httpd port 2812
  use address 127.0.0.1
  allow admin:mybestpassword
```

you isntance only listen on localhost (127.0.0.1), so obviously won't answer on remote call.

Reading the monit cookbook readme (the one you linked too) there's an attribute to control this:

```
node['monit']['address'] – Local address to bind to for Monit's HTTPD interface. (default: nil)
```

Set `default['monit']['address'] = '0.0.0.0'` in your cookbook attributes file to configure it to listen on all available interfaces.

And an ACL to allow per the comment above in doc so finale attributes files should include (untested):

```
default['monit']['address'] = '0.0.0.0'
default['monit']['allow'] = ['0.0.0.0']
```

Comment: I'm still not getting a response remotely.

Comment: I've tried using `0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0` like this [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-monit)